# Get the highest number is excel files?

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I have several excel files all of them with several sheets, and I need to know the highest number between a range. I dont know if there is a function or script that can do this for me or if I have to create a custom script...

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What have you tried? Are these CSV files? What is the headers and expected data of the CSV files?

Comment: You need to write a custom script. Start doing a research on how to loop through multiple Excel files, then research how to use the [WorksheetFunction.Max method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.max). There is a lot of content in the web how to do that. Start on your own and if you get stuck or errors come back with your code and a question to it.

Comment: Your question is unclear: Are you looking for an Excel Macro, a VBA-program, or a POSIX shell script (in which case you would need to specify the format of your file, since Excel can save a spreadsheet in several formats).